# python typing: detach function signature type declaration from function definition

Tags: python, typing

I want to ensure a couple of functions implement the same interface via type checking.
How'd I do this? Would I use additional tooling for this? 
For completeness: I'm using mypy as a type checker.

Example:

```py
binaryFunction = Callable[[float, float], float]

def plus(a, b):
   return a + b

def minus(a, b):
    return a - b
```

How can I specify that both `plus` and `minus` adhere to the binaryFunction interface?

what seems to works:

```py
checkedPlus: binaryFunction = plus
checkedMinus: binaryFunction = minus
```

but this just looks very weird; I feel it's not at all pythonic, so I'd refrain from doing this, unless I get convinced it's indeed the way to achieve this.

I've one possible solution in my answer below, but feel like there's room for improvement.

Comment: Why do you need to make sure they implement the same interface? Usually this is because they will be put ina lookup table or map, in which case *that* is where they type enforcement happens: specify the map as having values of tyle `binaryFunction`. IOW don't worry about the functions themselves, worry about how they are used.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart different algorithms for the same task, and they're not called through lookup-table/map. The actual callsite will have a different owner. And I'd expect a function to specify what it's interface is, way more than what the caller puts into it.

Comment: It sounds like they don't actually need to be the same then. And a function doesn't define its interface, it defines its signature. A function can *conform to* or *implement* an interface defined by something else.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart your wording correction is right of course, but could you explain why I wouldn't want to check that they implement the same interface? It makes the mental model of the thing smaller if I only think about one interface - I think that's the core of why I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, but is either a bit repetitive or assigns

```py
from typing import Callable

def binaryFunction(implementation: Callable[[float, float], float]) -> Callable[[float, float], float]:
    return implementation

# assign signature to name instead of repeating it's literal

_binaryFunctionSignature: Callable[[float, float], float])
def binaryFunction(implementation: _binaryFunctionSignature) -> _binaryFunctionSignature:
    return implementation

@binaryfunction
def decoratedPlus(a, b): 
    return a + b

decoratedPlus(1, 1j)  # fails type checking but runs - as expected
```

Is this the way? Could it be improved?